# I want to make a URL from record in a custom object in lightning email template

Tags: custom-object, url, merge-field, lightning-email-template, relatedrecord

"Hello everyone,

I need help creating a URL in a Lightning email template in Salesforce. But what's special about my situation is that I need the email URL to take me to a path similar to this one: [https://somethingsomething--SB3.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/CustomObject2__c/{{{CustomObject__r.CustomObject2__c.Id}}}/view](https://somethingsomething--SB3.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/CustomObject2__c/%7B%7B%7BCustomObject__r.CustomObject2__c.Id%7D%7D%7D/view).
The problem is that when modifying the email template, the 'insert Merge fields' section doesn't show the related object ID that I need to access. The custom object, CustomObject__c, is the object I'm currently on, and I need to extract the ID from a lookup field that's related to the CustomObject2__c object. Is there a way to implement this?

Thanks for your help."

Comment: Hi there, just to clarify do you see the CustomObject2 lookup field that exists on the object you're currently working on?

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385133&type=1) about cross-object formula fields?

Comment: Hi @CallumMacErlich ! Yeah, the lookup field exist in the current object. So both objects are related. I have a workaround meanwhile, the solution is a formula field that pulls the other custom object's data into the current object's field options. In order for this to happen, the two objects need to be related - i.e. the object with the fields on it needs to be a lookup or master-detail relationship to the object you're sending the email from.

Comment: Hi @DavidCheng , thanks for the domentation provided. As a workaround I used a formula field that pulls the other custom object's data into te current object's fields option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although a work around has been identified (using formula fields to pull data to from the related objects), it's also worth adding that to achieve this you don't need to pull the ID field from the related object.

The Lookup field field stores the ID of the related record, so in this case the following will actually provide the same information:

```
CustomObject__c.CustomObject2__r.Id
```

```
CustomerObject__c.CustomObject2__c
```

Comment: Thanks Callum! This is works perfect for me!!!